# Is there any zero-value iota test network?

Tags: transaction, testnet, debugging

I would like to play around with iota transactions without putting real value tokens at risk.

Is there any zero-value iota test network?

Comment: Use your own private IOTA testnet.
Reference: https://github.com/schierlm/private-iota-testnet

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [IOTA testnet](https://blog.iota.org/the-iota-testnet-training-wheels-for-the-community-fd65dbdddb3b), simply by connecting your application to a public testnet node. It is designed to be lighter and quicker than the IOTA mainnet (transactions are confirmed more quickly), but parallel to the mainnet in almost all other respects. IOTA developers and community members will be happy to give you free test iotas to use; see the linked resource for instructions on how to get started.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: How do I contact IOTA developers and community members to get test iotas?

Answer (score 2):

You can do 0 value transactions on the main net without using tokens.

Comment: This is somewhat a comment, not an answer. I am not aware that this is possible. Can you expand on how this works?

Comment: @5chdn it is possible in theory (if you "manually" send out a zero-value transaction), but I think the official wallet interface doesn't currently let the user send zero-value transactions, unfortunately.

Comment: It works. I am playing with the Java API and using fresh seeds with 0 tokens, and my transactions are fine